# How to render the same path for different layout-routes in React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to render a specific route for two different layout routes. Basically this route must render for the public and private layouts, but with the same path.

Something like this

```
createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <PublicLayout />,
    children: [
      // other routes in public layout
      {
        path: '/legal/*',
        element: <Legal />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    element: <PrivateLayout />,
    children: [
      // other routes in private layout
      {
        path: '/legal/*',
        element: <Legal />,
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

The `Legal` component fits in both layouts, but in this configuration only the public layout will be rendered.
The splat in the path is because `Legal` has descendent routes.

I've tried a wrapper component but it just doesn't render.

```
export default function LegalRouter() {
  const isOnline = true

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={isOnline ? <Layout /> : <PublicLayout />}>
        <Route element={<Legal />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render two routes on the same path within the same `Routes` component, so you'll likely need to abstract a *new* route guard component that conditionally renders a "Public" or "Private" wrapper component. You can't just directly use `PublicLayout` and `PrivateLayout` here though since you don't want to do any redirection but instead just want to swap out the UI, e.g. the "UI/layout" components from each.

Example:

```
const PublicPrivateLayout = () => {
  const /* condition */ = /* compute condition value */;

  const Wrapper = /* condition */ ? PublicWrapper : PrivateWrapper;

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Outlet />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

```
createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <PublicLayout />,
    children: [
      // public-only routes
    ],
  },
  {
    element: <PrivateLayout />,
    children: [
      // private-only routes
    ],
  },
  {
    element: <PublicPrivateLayout />,
    children: [
      // public or private routes
      {
        path: '/legal/*',
        element: <Legal />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: Very nice, worked perfectly.